# CGAffineTransformMakeScale animation not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, animation

I have a viewcontroller with a view that I am dismissing using a UIView animation to scale it down to 0 before removing it. My code for dismissing it is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:_dismissAnimationDuration
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^(void) {
                     _menuContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 0.0);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(popUpMenuDidClose)])
                     {
                         [_delegate popUpMenuDidClose];
                     }

                     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                     [self removeFromParentViewController];
                 }];
```

That works perfectly when building from XCode 5 onto devices running both iOS 7 and iOS 8. But, as soon as I build to iOS 8 from XCode 6 (beta 6 and beta 7) the view just cuts away instead of animating. If that wasn't weird enough as soon as I change the target scale to (0.001, 0.001) it animates fine regardless of XCode version. Any ideas as to why I can't animate to an actual (0.0, 0.0) scale with XCode 6?

Comment: I have the same problem with the iOS8GM... no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So after speaking with a developer at Apple the reasoning I got back was that some base frameworks need to work with the inverses of transform matrices quite often, and since there is no inverse for the zero matrix the animation just returns out to avoid crashing. Hopefully this post has helped others who ran into a similar situation.

Comment: I think from this we can infer that the solution would be that which is proposed by @guptron by setting a none zero value like CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01); it definitely worked for me, thanks

Comment: That is not a solution, that is a hack... Does Apple intend to fix that bug?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz It isn't exactly a bug, so I don't believe they have a plan to change how scaling works. I also wouldn't call scaling with a non-zero matrix a hack based on how the underlying math works

Comment: I understood the comment about the math behind it, still, it doesn't make sense that you can't animate to a zero scale.

Answer (score 6):

If acceptable for you, set the scale values to 0.01 like so:

`_menuContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24878716/1672161)

Comment: This saved me possibly hours of frustration.  My code using (0,0) works fine in xcode using obj-c but in my Xamarin code I had to use (0.01f, 0.01f)