# UIView animateWithDuration jumps to final transform without animation

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have the following code to create flip transition. The `fromView` does not animate the transform and jumps to the final value but the `toView` correctly animates transform. What could be wrong here?

```
  toView.hidden = NO;
  toView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                   animations:^{
                     fromView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
                   }
                   completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     fromView.hidden = YES;
                     fromView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                                      animations:^{
                                        toView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
                                      }
                                      completion:nil];
                   }];
```

Comment: What is the value of `finished` in the first completion block? If it's `NO`, then either somewhere else in your code or the SDK is modifying the state of that view (frame, transform, etc) before the animation has the chance to complete.

Comment: The value of `finished` is YES so it did finish acc to that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the scale can be animated to 0 value because of divide by zero issues in the transformation matrix.

Check out in this link.
http://www.wenda.io/questions/217747/uiview-scale-to-0-using-cgaffinetransformmakescale.html

And this [CGAffineTransformMakeScale animation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653192/cgaffinetransformmakescale-animation-not-working)

You can instead use a small value to scale to and then hide the view after that like below

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                     animations:^{
                         fromView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 1);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         fromView.hidden = YES;
                         fromView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                                          animations:^{
                                              toView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
                                          }
                                          completion:nil];
                     }];
```